# Loaded time is without hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: r, posixct, rpostgresql

i load on local computer (Mac) with RPostgreSQL file from PostgreSQL and i have time instead of `"2015-02-03 12:12:12" "2015-02-03"`. i need true time, please help.

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
command <- "SELECT * FROM xxx;"
xxx <- dbSendQuery(con, xxx)
```

OR

```
xxx <- dbReadTable(con, "xxx")

class(xxx$time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: If your data is of class `POSIXct` or `POSIXlt` it does contain complete time and date information, even though it might not be printed that way. Try `strptime(xxx$time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` to convert it to text.

Comment: Thank you. But i have time without hours, minutes and seconds:
> summary(xxx$time)

                 Min.               1st Qu.                Median                  Mean               3rd Qu.                  Max. 

"2014-02-21 00:00:00" "2014-11-26 00:00:00" "2015-02-05 00:00:00" "2015-01-26 14:23:39" "2015-04-17 00:00:00" "2015-06-09 00:00:00"